# Using MySQL on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, odbc

I am using the `ODBC` connector to access a MySQL db from Visual Studio 2008 and I'm facing performance problems when dealing with crystal reports and to solve this I need a native connector to visual studio. If someone has had a similar problem and knows a solution or tools (freeware preferable), I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 7):

You want [Connector/Net](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/net/)

**Update:**  This link should take you to a more recent version:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below link: You will get more knowledge:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MySQLCrystal.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need add reference to `Mysql.Data.dll`. Put the `dll` file in `Bin` folder and right click  - add reference. Its sample.

Answer (score 0):

Connector/Net *is* the native provider you are looking for.  If you're having trouble using it then you should open a new question asking how to get it working with crystal reports.  I don't use crystal reports, so I can't help you there myself.